# Python - Return starting index of exact match to sub-string

Tags: python, string, substring

I need to find the starting index of a string when there is an exact match to a sub-string.

```
line = "Your family and You are invited to my party"
```

I want to find the starting index of `You`i.e. 16

I have tried

```
line.find("You")
```

however that returns `0`

Then I tried,

```
import re
print(re.findall('\\bYou\\b', line))
```

But it returns a list with the sub-string in it

```
["You"]
```

Comment: That returns `0` because you have a string `"You"` at position `0`. The `"You"` of `"Your"`. I think what you are looking for in a exact match of a word, a word being a collection of alphabets separated by a space.

Comment: Good find @Rawing that answer should answer the OP's query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fine using a regex then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956274/how-to-find-index-of-an-exact-word-in-a-string-in-python) should address your issue.

Applying that to your question. We get

```
import re
a = re.search(r'\b(you)\b', 'Your family and you are invited to the party')
print a.start()
```

Which gives `16`

Does this work for all possible positions of "you"? (start, middle and end)? Let's check

```
str1 = "you hi"
str2 = "hi you"
str3 = "hi you hi"
re.search(r'\b(you)\b', str1).start()
# output is 0
re.search(r'\b(you)\b', str2).start()
# output is 3
re.search(r'\b(you)\b', str3).start()
# output is 3
```

**UPDATE 1: Case insensitive matching**

In case you want a case insensitive match use `re.IGNORECASE` like this

```
re.search(r'\b(you)\b', str3, re.IGNORECASE).start()
```

**UPDATE 2: Passing a variable instead of hardcoded string in the regex**

```
str = "Your family and you are invited to the party"
word_to_search = "you"
re_string = r"\b({})\b".format(word_to_search)
re.search(re_string, str).start()
#output is 16
```

Comment: How do I pass a variable into `re.search` with regular expressions i.e `re.search(r'\b('+key+')\b', str3).start()` where `key = 'you'`

Comment: @BryceRamgovind refer to the second comment in the answer by DeepSpace (link in my answer). It says  "Like you would with any Python string. You can concat or use .format, ie word = 'laugh' ; re.search(r'\b({})\b'.format(word), string)". I'll try it out and update my answer

Comment: @BryceRamgovind updated my answer after trying out the suggestion in the answer I linked. Feel free to comment if it doesn't work for you

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search` to get appropriate position of your pattern.
For example:

```
import re
line = "Your family and You are invited to my party"
res = re.search('\\bYou\\b', line)
```

It gives a result that looks like

> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 19), match='You'>

Then

```
beg, end = res.span()
```

where variable `beg` stores required index.

Comment: How do I extract the int 16 from the result?

Comment: just do `res.start()`

Answer (score 1):

This Should work

```
import re
line = "Your family and You are invited to my party"
re.search('\\bYou\\b', line).start()
```

to get the exact index