# How to add char to unknown string length?

Tags: python, string

I have a string and I know it includes the word "python" but I don't know how many characters the string has.
I want to add "." before "python"
for example:

```
     str = input("enter string")
     #Here I need help
     print(str)#The output will be the user's input and "." before the word "python" let say str = "I love python" the output will be "I love .python"
```

Comment: What code have you tried to solve it? @VictorHanukayev

Comment: I have no idea to solve it

Comment: Look at `string.split` and `string.join` methods! They will help guide you to the solution!

Comment: You can also use `if` condition to check if `python` is in the user's input, then replace `python` with `.python`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of an exact word in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956274/how-to-find-index-of-an-exact-word-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: `find`and `replace` string methods can be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't exactly get your question but look at this, maybe it'll help.

```
inp=input('enter input ::')  # taking user input

new_str=inp.replace('python','.python') #just replace python will .python in user input

print(new_str)
```

The output will be like :

```
enter input ::i love python
i love .python
```